# Compilation issues with Mix and Match Objective-C & Swift Cocoapod

Tags: objective-c, swift, build, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm working on a large mixed Objective-C and Swift codebase. I'm trying to move some of the code into a separate framework. This is going to end up being imported into the main project via a Cocoapod. The separate framework will end up having both Objective-C and Swift code.

So far I've moved all of the files for the new separate framework out of the main project and into a new folder. I've referenced these new files via a podspec and I'm importing them back into the main project as a development pod. All I'm trying to do right now is get this new framework to build on its own, I'm not trying to build it as part of the entire project yet.

The part I'm currently stuck on is, when it builds, in the MySplitOutFramework-Swift.h that it generates there is a a compilation error. The compilation error is on the line `#import <MySplitOutFramework/MySplitOutFramework.h>`. The error say 'this file cannot be found'.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Is it some kind of circular dependency?

Comment: Isn't that how you import things in Objective-C? Swift should only require `import MySplitOutFramework`

Comment: I'm talking about the auto-generated header file. The one Xcode makes so Objective-C code can read your Swift code. That file has that line in it. I didn't write it myself.